# Problem on springs

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, spring

[image]
(ans: D)
I have tried the problem by finding relation between extensions of the springs which comes out to be F/3k for the upper and lower spring and 2F/3k for the middle two. And then i get stuck as i dont know how to proceed further

[image]

Comment: Can you show us your free body diagrams?

Comment: This problem can be simplified by capitalizing on the symmetry of the system.  If we situate an observer at the center of the middle string (half-way between the two pulleys), then, relative to this observer, the attachment at the wall moves to the left by a displacement x and the block moves to the right with an equal displacement x; and the point on string where the observer is situated does not move at all.  If the upper pulley moves to the right by a displacement y, the upper spring increases in length by y+x.  And the spring between the upper pulley and the block increases by x-y.

Comment: @ChetMiller I think the upper spring actually increases in length by $2y+x$ because the total length of the upper *and* lower springs and the strings wrapped around the pulleys increases by $4y+2x$.

Comment: @gandalf61 If the upper pulley moves to the right by a displacement y (relative to an observer situated at the center of the middle string), the right end of the upper spring moves to the right by an equal amount (because the point at the middle of the center string does not move in this moving frame of reference).  And we already said that the left end of the upper spring moves to the left a displacement x (in this frame of reference).

Comment: @ChetMiller Think about the distance *following* the string and spring between the middle observer and the wall (or, equivalently, between the middle observer and the block). This distance changes by $2y+x$, which must equal the extension of the upper spring.

Comment: @gandalf61. You are aware that I am using a moving frame of reference that translates along with the material point at the center of the middle string, right?

Comment: @ChetMiller If you use $y+x$ do you get the correct answer $\text{(d) }\frac{10F}{9k}$ ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96862/discussion-between-chet-miller-and-gandalf61).

Comment: I solved it a different way, accounting for the changes in the lengths of all the springs and the constant lengths of the strings and got $\frac{10F}{9k}$.  So, I stand corrected.

Comment: And you were right about the extension of the upper spring being 2y+x.